# What is the best approach to bind data to ReportViewer control? (DataAdapter vs DataReader)

Tags: binding, dataset, reportviewer, datareader

I have 2 approaches to bind data to ReportViewer control. Which one is better? Could you please give me some advice?

**Approach 1: Using SqlDataAdapter**

```
Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
Dim conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connString)
Try
    conn.Open()
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    adapter.Fill(dt)
Catch ex As Exception
Finally
    conn.Close()
End Try

Dim ds As New ReportDataSource(dataSourceName, dt)
rViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
rViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(ds)
rViewer.LocalReport.Refresh()
```

**Approach 2: Using SqlDataReader**

```
Dim dt As New DataTable()
Dim conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connString)
Try
    conn.Open()
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
    Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    dt.Load(reader)
    reader.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
Finally
    conn.Close()
End Try

Dim ds As New ReportDataSource(dataSourceName, dt)
rViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
rViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(ds)
rViewer.LocalReport.Refresh()
```

Comment: you are very welcome to comment, accept or ask for more infos. That's the way StackOverflow should work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have to choose between the two I would go for the first one cause a dataset is populated internally using a datareader.
Your second sample converts a datareader in a dataset.
The first option should be slightly faster. 
Another option would be to use objects (entities) as datasource.
You can find more infos [here](http://www.gotreportviewer.com/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was wondering if we can bind DataReader directly to ReportViewer. I have tried to use that, but it seemed there were some enigmatic errors here (due to the urgency of my project, I had to change my approach without investigating what issue occurred). Have you ever tried that?

Comment: Yes, you can't do that because of the nature of it.Datareader is not a disconnected set of data, like the dataset. Datareader remains connected to the database until you close the connection. It fetches one row at a time. ReportViewer can't managed it cause it needs a disconnected (enumerable) set of data.

Comment: @nguyen190887: no problem at all. I would be pleased if you could just accecpt (with the check button next to my answer) my answer. Stackoverflow works that way: you accept, down-vote or up-vote answers so the user (me) is rewarded.